# Remove UTF-8 Characters from List

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to remove certain characters that are represented below as '\u00a0' and show a black question mark once encoded to utf-8. I'm trying to trim away just these characters while leaving the rest of the values. Below is a shortened version of the longer list imported as 'test.json' to this project.

`["\u00a0", "Symbol Lookup", null, "16:00:01", "$\u00a0335.56\u00a0 "]`

Here's the script I've written:

```
filename = 'test.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    price_list = json.load(f)

wst = '\u00a0'
wst_utf = wst.encode()
print(wst)
print(wst_utf)

for elem in price_list:
    if elem:
        elem.remove(wst,'')

print(price_list[4])
```

I was expecting to see the black question marks removed but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: U+00A0 is a hard, non-breakable space. Replacng it with a space should suffice.

Comment: do you mean `replace`, instead of `remove`? -- and 2nd: strings are static, so you cannot change an existing string. You should use `elem = elem.replace(wst, '')`

Comment: Where do you see black question marks? Perhaps there's a way to solve *that* issue directly, without changing how you read the json

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I did have a typo with 'remove' and 'replace' - with that corrected, I'm still seeing the black question marks on element 4 in the list noted in my original question. When I print(price_list[4]), I see this result:

Comment: $�335.56� 
and my json file is representing these UTF-8 markers as \u00a0

Comment: I needed to append to a new list - I'm new to this but slowly figuring out the basics! Thanks so much for the help folks. Problem resolved.